# Why use %r only for regular expressions matching more than one '/' character?

Tags: ruby

I know that using `%r{some regex}` in Ruby will automatically escape all the forward slashes in my regex, but apparently we aren't supposed to use it if there's only one forward slash in the regex.

I've seen this mentioned in multiple Ruby style guides (namely [Styleguide](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby) and [Ruby-style-guide](https://www.relishapp.com/womply/ruby-style-guide/docs/percent-literals)), and Rubocop flags it by default, but I can't find an explanation for it.

Why not use `%r` if there is only one forward slash in the regex? Just because this notation only helps you not escape one slash doesn't seem like a good reason to not use it at all.

Comment: It doesn't escape the slashes, it just doesn't make a slash a meta-character that needs to be escaped in he first place.

Comment: Well I guess `/regex/` is more common and more likely to be colorized the right way in some random editors. And `%r(/)` is 5 char length while `/\//` is 4.

Comment: "Why not use %r if there is only one forward slash in the regex?" Why not use it all the time? Don't let the style police tell you what to do. There's too much of that nonsense in the ruby community as it is.

Comment: There is a point to be made about following the style-guides, but on our team I tell them to read the guides, understand *why* certain styles are recommended, then use what results in the clearest and most easily read and maintained code, that also still is done in the Ruby-way. Writing Ruby like Perl, Java or C doesn't work but that still leaves some wiggle room.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> apparently you aren't supposed to use it if there's only one forward slash in the regex.

This is not true.

> I've seen this mentioned in multiple Ruby style guides (namely here and here)

You are jumping to your conclusion based on some limited observation. It is just these people's own decision. Whomever feel sympathy with these people might attempt to spread this practice though.

However, I see some rationale in such claim. What I think is that in various occasions, Ruby has several ways to express the same thing. Randomly choosing one way or another makes the code difficult to read and can induce human errors. So we should stick to a single notation when possible. This applies to regex literal as well. Since `//` is the most concise and the unmarked regex literal, we should stick to it whenever possible.

Whether to use `%r` notation should thus depend on whether the pros (avoiding the necessity to escape slashes) outweighs the cons (departing from using the standard `//` notation and/or using a longer notation). It seems that those people judged that a single slash (single occurrence of escape) does not make the pros sufficient to outweigh the cons, but two or more do. And that makes sense as the `%r{}` notation takes two more characters than `//`, so it becomes a tie when the latter needs two escaping, and beyond that, `%r{}` becomes the shorter notation.

Comment: I switch over to `%r{...}` pretty quick if there's an abundance of slashes in the pattern. For example, the omni-present: `%r{\Ahttps?://}`.

Answer (score 2):

One of the more visually irritating aspects of programming is dealing with escaped characters in strings/paths and regular expressions. It's so irritating that years ago it was given a name "[leaning toothpick syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome)".

The introduction of `%r`, `%q` and `%Q`, in Ruby, and similar in Perl and other languages, was an attempt to reduce the visual noise. Dealing with long strings and patterns containing slashes can fatigue our eyes and numb our brains, which leads to errors and bugs.

Use common-sense and group/team consensus to determine whether to use `//` or `%r{}` or other delimiters, and remember to be merciful for your future-self and/or team members when dealing with LTS. Debugging at 3AM and staring at escaped slashes can be frustrating.

As far as escapes being automatically added, no, Ruby doesn't do that. PHP had "[magic quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_quotes)" so maybe someone crossed their thoughts and confused the two.

Comment: Visual noise was not really a concern in Perl, that was already part of the language. Giving people *options* was the primary concern, part of Perl's embrace of the [TMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) culture.

Comment: It wasn't a concern in _some_ people's minds. It was one of those things we worked on when programming in Perl. I was actually commended for writing extremely readable Perl years after having written an app at work. The guys maintaining it loved how easy it was to understand and read. But I learned to do that reading other people's C-like Perl code and after much gnashing of my teeth.

Comment: Like C, Perl's got a lot of syntax baggage that can't be avoided. I did my best to keep it clean when I was writing a lot of Perl, but I'd bet your absolutely most pristine Perl looks like a train-wreck compared to your average Ruby code. The simplest solution in Perl is almost impenetrable to outsiders, it's just so dense. The simplest solution in Ruby is usually quite pleasant.

Comment: Exactly why we no longer write production code in Perl. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such limitation in the documentation on Ruby literals. I would use whichever appears more readable, and in my opinion the `%r` notation clearly wins when there are slashes inside the regular expression.